# Is there any example using passing data integer between 2 view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

My data is just number, I want pass it from VC1 to VC2 for next calculation, not for showing at label. Maybe that's not a problem for passing data string using code below. But I don't know how to pass number integer, like `a = b x c`. I want to bring that a from VC1 to VC2 for next step calculation like `a + d = e`. I declare for that a, b, c, d, e is int at .h file

This is how I use to pass string data. But how to do it for integer?

```
ProcessViewController *ProcessData = [[ProcessViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];        
self.processViewData = ProcessData;
processViewData.labelViewString = labelView.text; // pass to VC2
[self presentModalViewController:ProcessData animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .h file of the second view controller you need to add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) int someInt;
```

and obviously synthesize this property in the .m file for the second VC.

then once you've initialized the ProcessViewController, you can set the property on it from within the first VC:

```
processData.someInt = someOtherInt;
[self presentModalViewController];
```

Edit: Note that you could also use an NSNumber property if you wanted (not sure why you would in this case). If you did so and you arent using ARC then you would also need to release the property.

Comment: great glad i could help. good luck with your app! i edited that last little sentence frag out there. sorry bout that

Comment: Just an clarification, you don't need to release the C/C++ native data types, only the objects (the one you alloc). So you don't have to release an Int (actually you can't).